# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<mp> has no method 'toPOJO'

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'toPOJO'

Comment: Is this a visualforce or javascript question ? For anyone to understand it may be usefull if you add the whole page code and explain what you are trying to do..

Comment: Tanks for your support. I have resolved problem my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this looks to be entirely javascript.

Not knowing much about google charting, I don't know how much help i'm going to be. However I can tell you that a cursory glance of the google chart api docs shows no toPOJO method. Additionally, that terminology doesn't make much sense, as a POJO, in my experience, almost always refers to a 'plain old java object' Since neither of the languages you could be using (apex, or javascript) is java, the toPOJO call doesn't make much sense. Did you copy/paste this code from a java project?

If you're trying to include google charts on your visual force pages, I suggest you look at this recent app exchange app from salesforce Labs: [myCharts](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4ablEAB) it's an unmanaged package so you can not only utilize the charts and chart building tools within it, but you can see the code to discover how they're constructed.

Answer (score 2):

So, just a few thoughts here.

1. It looks like you're coding in javascript, not apex or java. Javascript, to my knowledge, has no builtin toPOJO method.
2. Perhaps you could explain more about what you're looking for here? or trying to do? I suspect, given chart.getDataTable() that you're manipulating a google chart?

Comment: Here I want to display labels on each stack using this wrapper class on Google visualization Api charts.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that. The more information you give in your question, the better we are able to help you.

Comment: Hi kevin i have updated my question above